# Newtonsoft Json - Serialize DateTime type of DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime, datatable

I have a problem when serializing DataTable to Json using `Newtonsoft.Json`. This is reductive code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Prop", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now);

        ObjCls cls = new ObjCls();
        cls.Prop = DateTime.Now;

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());

        string json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented, settings);
        string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cls, Formatting.Indented, settings);

        Console.WriteLine(json1);
        Console.WriteLine("===========================================");
        Console.WriteLine(json2);
    }

    class ObjCls
    {
        public DateTime Prop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I got (same result if I don't add `IsoDateTimeConverter`):

```
[
  {
    "Prop": "2016-04-03T16:02:09.0163201"
  }
]
===========================================
{
  "Prop": "2016-04-03T16:02:09.0173201+07:00"
}
```

Could you explain why these datatime results are difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first date kind is `Unspecified` whereas the second is `Local`. The reason why the first is `Unspecified` is because of the weakly typed nature of a DataTable. If you debug your code and expand the Rows collection of the DataTable until you reach the actual date value you will notice that it is `Unspecified`. If you want to always serialize in ISO 8601 UTC you could use the following settings:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;

string json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented, settings);
string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cls, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

This being said you still have the problem of losing the DateTime kind with the DataTable. I would recommend you using a DateTimeOffset in this case as this will preserve the local timezone offset:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Prop", typeof(DateTimeOffset));
dt.Rows.Add(DateTimeOffset.Now);

ObjCls cls = new ObjCls();
cls.Prop = DateTimeOffset.Now;

object o = DateTime.Now;
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

string json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented, settings);
string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cls, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

And ideally you should never use `DataTable`.